# Using the Well of Many Worlds

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

My group is about to come into possession of the wondrous item, the [Well of Many Worlds](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/well-of-many-worlds).

At the conclusion of this current module I am going to take the group to level 20 with a few Mythic tiers.

What I'd like to know is how to use the Well of Many Worlds. The item description states it randomly links you to another realm, however I cannot find any table with random generation.

How have you used it in your adventures?

Comment: Historical note: In 3.5rd edition D&D, there was a standard random plane table that a number of magical items and effects used. This table represented the proprietary "Great Wheel" cosmology, however, and so was not reproduced in Pathfinder. I'm not sure why there's no replacement table, but presumably the Paizo devs decided not to make assumptions about which cosmology their players would be playing in.

Answer (score 3):

Paizo's [Pathfinder Chronicles: Classic Treasures Revisited (PFRPG)](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8dmn?Pathfinder-Chronicles-Classic-Treasures-Revisited) has more detail on the Well of Many Worlds and includes two tables to roll on for planar destinations (one of which is for demi-planes), some suggestions on using it in a campaign, some of it's uses in Golarion's history and some other related details on it's use such as researching locations and variants on the basic well.